# How to Connect Samsung Galaxy GT-N8000 with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, galaxy-tab

I have samsung galaxy note 10.1 and model GT-N8000, I want to connect it to android studio and want to run my own made app. But my android studio not showing anything and even pc do not detect it , not even popping up notification to show me that some thing is connected. I check this device to other computers but got same thing.

So what could be a problem. I have done resetting , but nothing is helpful, Updated driver, installed the google driver for usb, installed the universal driver. But nothing is really helping. So at least pc should detect it but its not.

Any solution. ? Please help

Comment: Install usb driver... & turn on usb debugging from developer option in settings.

Comment: have you enabled usb debugging?

Comment: You are saying that the device isn't detected by PC? Make sure that the cable which you are using is fine. At the very least, when you connect your device to PC via USB cable it should show charging icon. Is it showing it?

Comment: If the device is charging then it means that USB cable is correct. If so, use Device Manager and see if your device is listed there.

Comment: You have installed incorrect driver.

Comment: ya usb debugging enabled

Comment: I'm having this problem when connecting with any cable that is not the charger cable (which is typeC-typeC). Problem is, my new computer doesn't have a typeC port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that you chose *Connect as Camera* or *PTP* on your phone.

Go to developer settings and activate *Adb-debugging* or *USB-debugging*.

Also check, whether you have installed the correct drivers. Try to reinstall the correct drivers.

And make sure that neither your USB cable nor your USB-drive is faulty. If so try to use another cable and different usb-drive.

You could also try to connect your phone wirelessly to Android Studio

Comment: Oh you remind me about cable, Yes there is some sort of losing in tab side , when I pressed it hard, it works , thanks

Comment: could you please provide exact driver link

Comment: You could look up your specific driver at the Samsung-Homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try -

1. Go to settings, developer options and turn USB Debugging on. If it's off, Android Studio will not detect your phone.
2. If you PC is not detecting your device, either your USB cable is faulty or your USB drive. Only way to know is connect your phone to another USB-Drive or connect it using another cable.